# Enter another page when pressing AlertController's option buttons ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile-development

I have an AlertController which pops after adding a new note. It has two options: "new note" and "see notes". When press "see notes", it should enter another pages to see list of notes. When press "new note", it should stay on this page for adding a new note. So, how to enter another page pressing an alertCtrl option button?

Now I have:

```
  showConfirm() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'What do you want to do else?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'New note',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('New note');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'See notes',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('See notes');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `handler:` method call the `NavController` and `push` the required page.

Please see below:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

showConfirm() {
  let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'What do you want to do else?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'New note',
        handler: () => {
          this.navCtrl.push(NewNotesPage);
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'See notes',
        handler: () => {
          this.navCtrl.push(SeeNotesPage);
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  confirm.present();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  showConfirm() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Use this lightsaber?',
      message: 'Do you agree to use this lightsaber to do good across the intergalactic galaxy?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Disagree',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Disagree clicked');
            this.seeNotes(NotesPage);            
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Agree',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Agree clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
  seeNotes(str:any){
    this.navCtrl.push(str);
  }
```